# lookup value based on partial value

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a set of batch numbers in a sheet which are alphanumeric code as follows

```
sdc234
fgh345
ght587
jki876
```

The alphabets of the batch number represent a product code. For example

```
sdc = 20499999
fgh = 45999999
ght = 67999992
jki = 56700000
```

The above relation is in another sheets.
I want to match product code with batch number directly. How do i lookup a product code based on this partial info ?

Comment: do the batch numbers always contain the same number of letters and numbers (in your example 3 letters and 3 numbers)?

Comment: No, that was just for a example. We have about 500 products and each three digit alphabets represent a unique product. But yes,the length of alphabets is always 3 and length of number will be 4 in the alphanumeric code. So a total of 7 will be the length of alphanumeric code

Comment: Please see the following link [merge two worksheets by partial cell match](https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2013/09/20/merge-worksheets-excel-partial-match/). I hope you will find it helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You can sort your second table in an alphabetical order and use VLOOKUP with TRUE (approximate match) as your third argument.

Assuming the second table is in column A and B:

```
D       E
sdc234  =VLOOKUP(D1,A:B,2,TRUE)
fgh345  =VLOOKUP(D2,A:B,2,TRUE)
ght587  =VLOOKUP(D3,A:B,2,TRUE)
jki876  =VLOOKUP(D4,A:B,2,TRUE)
```

The output is as below:

```
D       E
sdc234  20499999
fgh345  45999999
ght587  67999992
jki876  56700000
```

**EDIT:**
Assuming your product code is always 3 letters, you can use the LEFT function to get the first 3 letters and then use that as the lookup value. This way you can use the exact match as your third argument:

```
sdc234  =VLOOKUP(LEFT(D1,3),A:B,2,FALSE)
fgh345  =VLOOKUP(LEFT(D2,3),A:B,2,FALSE)
ght587  =VLOOKUP(LEFT(D3,3),A:B,2,FALSE)
jki876  =VLOOKUP(LEFT(D4,3),A:B,2,FALSE)
```

Credits to **Mladen Savic**'s comment for making me think of this solution.

Comment: Please check edit solution. Though this will only work if your product code is only 3 letters for each product.

Comment: If i use approximate match, what will happen in this case. if i have sdc435 and fdc435 which have two different set of code 20344444,20356666 respectively? There is a chance that excel will return one code for both the batches

Comment: It will actually give you the correct figure code. but since all your product codes are only 3 letters, you can just use FALSE as you third argument.

Comment: It will actually give you the correct code. but since all your product codes are only 3 letters, you can just use FALSE as you third argument and look up only the first three letters.@rajendra kodavaty